# cannot POST - What's wrong with my POST request? Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to learn node and have an issue with my POST request. I want to add a name and number to a list of contacts.

Here is my post functionality

```
// create
const generateId = () => {
  const personId = Math.random(...persons.map((p) => p.id));
  return personId;
};

app.post('/persons', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;

  if ((!body.name, !body.number)) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'content missing'
    });
  }
  const person = {
    name: body.name,
    number: body.number,
    id: generateId()
  };
  persons = persons.concat(person);

  res.json(person);
});
```

Here is my hardcoded contacts as a reference

```
let persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Arto Hellas',
    number: '010-111111'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ada Lovelace',
    number: '440-123456'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Dan Abramov',
    number: '330-349994'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mary Poppendieck',
    number: '210-113578'
  }
];
```

I'm trying to add a

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "Number": "12334"
}
```

When doing sending the request I see this: Cannot POST /api/persons

With a random ID from a generateId function that I'm hoping works.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue with your code?

Comment: I receive this message, Cannot POST /api/persons. Wish I could give more info however this is my first time touching node.

Comment: Please use this Console.log(body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POST /persons` instead of `POST /api/persons`.

Your route is `app.post('/persons',`, then you need to take a request with path is `/persons`.

If you want to create a route like `POST /api/persons`, let's change your route to `app.post('/api/persons...`